# Recursive object instantiation (in PHP)?

Tags: php, oop, recursion

So in my PHP program I'm creating a calendar feature and one of the classes is "CalendarDay". What I want to do is be able to instantiate a new day for each day count, so for example `new CalendarDay (22)` means a new *22nd of the month date*. There is also a `show()` function used for displaying each day. The class itself functions normally but when I try instantiating new days using recursion it no longer seems to work as everything related to the instantiated object disappears from the webpage.

```
class CalendarDay{
  private $current_month;
  private $current_year;
  private $current_date;

  public $reminderSet;
  public $reminders;

  public function __construct($current_day_of_month){
    $current_year = date("Y");
    $current_month = date("m");

    $this->days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_month, $current_year);
    $this->current_date = date("d");
    $this->current_day_of_month = $current_day_of_month;
  }

  public function show(){
    $output = '<div class = "generator>"';
    //$output .= $this->current_date;
    //$output .= '<h1>' . $this->current_date . '</h1>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= $this->current_day_of_month;
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

My failed attempt at recursion:

```
for ($countTo31 == 0; $countTo31 == 31; $countTo31++){
    $holder = $countTo31;
    $date = new CalendarDay ($holder);
    $date->show();
}
```

For the reference, this original block of code without the recursion works normally:

```
$holder = $countTo31;
$date = new CalendarDay ($holder);
$date->show();
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? If you intend to have 31 `CalendarDay` objects then this method (and those in the answers) won't work as you overwrite the object with every iteration and therefore only ever end up with the last object created!

Answer (score -1):

I'm very confused with what you're trying to accomplish...

You have a "day" class which takes input to initialise a specific day but instead actually works out the current day based on `date("Y-m-d");`?.. And then outputs the input day anyway?

Honestly, it looks more like you want a "month" object

## Initial problems

1. You use `==` to *define* your starting point

   - `==` is not an assignment operator, it's a comparison.
   - It effectively adds an additional iteration of the loop at the start of the loop

     ```
      for($i == 1; $i < 5; $i++){
          echo $i;
      }

      // Loop 1:
      //    --> Notice on $i == 1
      //    --> Notice on $i < 5
      //    --> Notice on echo $i
      //    --> Notice on $i++

      // Loop 2:
            --> $i = 1 BECAUSE of the previous $i++
                       so the intended loop starts...
     ```
   - Additionaly the loop, in this case, should start with 1 not 0(!)
2. You use `==` to define your condition

   - `for` loops like yours work effectively as:

     ```
      for ( A ; B ; C ){
          // Do something...
      }

      // Loop works as:
      //     Check A against B
      //     If TRUE then "Do something..."
      //         and then do C
      //     IF FALSE then break
     ```
   - However, even if your assignment (`A`) was correct (i.e. `$countTo31 = 1`), it still wouldn't work because `1 !== 31` and therfore the loop `breaks` from the start
   - It should be `$countTo31 <= 31`
3. Looping over object, rewriting the variable

   - Your code currently rewrites the variable which holds the date object with every loop
   - Effectively you create an object to output the day, output that data, and instantly remove the object so that it can't be used for anyting else...
4. Your HTML output has a `"` in the wrong place:

   ```
   $output = '<div class = "generator>"';

   //Should be...

   $output = '<div class = "generator">';
   ```
5. Some of the variables in your class are not assigned or declared properly

   - `$current_month` is declared but never assigned
   - `$current_year` is declared but never assigned
   - `$current_day_of_month` is assigned but not declared
   - `$days_in_month` is assigned but not declared

## Interim solution

Without further information on what you are intending to do it isn't possible to give good/accurate guidance, so I will leave a working example which should show you what to do:

```
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(
    CAL_GREGORIAN,
    date("m"),
    date("Y")
);

for ($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++){
    echo "Day {$day}<br>";
}
```

## Proposed changes

It doesn't look as though you really even want a "day" class for the functions you're trying to implement. So, in my mind, it would be better to first create a "month" object with all of the days of the month and then have that generate a "day" object for each day of the month which then can gather the information for each day e.g. reminders.

Doing it this way you can then update each day as you go with, for example, user input or database data.

```
class Month
{
    private $month;
    private $year;
    private $days = [];

    public function __construct($month, $year)
    {
        $this->month    = $month;
        $this->year     = $year;
        $number_of_days = cal_days_in_month(
            CAL_GREGORIAN,
            $month,
            $year
        );

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_days; $i++){
            $date = "{$this->year}-{$this->month}-{$i}";
            // $days[] = new Day($date);
            $this->days[$i] = new Day($date);
        }   
    }

    public function getDay($day)
    {
        return $this->days[$day];
    }

    public function getNumberOfDays()
    {
        return count($this->days);
    }
}

class Day
{
    private $date;
    private $reminders = [];
    
    public function __construct($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        // Initialise day...
            # Get reminders
            # Get meetings
            # Get bills to pay
    }

    public function getReminders()
    {
        return $this->reminders;
    }
    public function setReminder($content, $time)
    {
        // Set reminders
        $this->reminders[] = [
            "content" => $content,
            "time"    => $time
        ];
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return date("d / m / Y", strtotime($this->date));
    }
}

$month = new Month(12, 2020);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $month->getNumberOfDays(); $i++){
    echo $month->getDay($i)->show()."<br>";
}
```